# Button action not working in selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium to click on a button and the **HTML** code for the button is like:

```
 div class="_1WZqU PNlAR" role="button">Join group</div
```

I tried with all possible solution:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('._1WZqU.PNlAR').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('_1WZqU PNlAR').click()
```

But its throwing an error **no such element:** Unable to locate element: `{"method":"css selector","selector":"._1WZqU.PNlAR"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
  button =   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Join group')]")))  
  button.click()
```

make sure you are importing :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Make sure element should not be in any frame/frameset/iframe.

If it is inside any frame , you have to switch the focus of your driver to that particular frame/iframe in order to interact with it.

Note : This is a **div** , the above code would work if and only if the div is clickable.